# Objective-C class for placing UI elements based on screen size

Tags: classes, objective-c, ios

I'm always programmatically creating and laying out UI elements in multiple ViewControllers and I've wanted an easy way to get relevant Screen information (sizes/points) globally using a helper class.

I've created a FlexibleScreen class and would like some constructive feedback.  In addition to the typical code review feedback of format, syntax, etc I would really like to know how well this solves my problem functionally and what suggestions you have about the design or what additional functionality I could add.

**FlexibleScreen.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FlexibleScreen : NSObject

+(CGSize)getScreenSize;
+(CGPoint)getCenter;
+(CGPoint)getCenterWithY:(double)y;
+(CGPoint)getCenterWithX:(double)x;

@end
```

**FlexibleScreen.m**

```
#import "FlexibleScreen.h"

@interface FlexibleScreen()

@property (assign) CGRect bounds;
@end


@implementation FlexibleScreen

+(CGSize)getScreenSize
{
    return CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
}

+(CGPoint)getCenter
{
    return CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2);
}

+(CGPoint)getCenterWithY:(double)y
{
    return CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, y);
}

+(CGPoint)getCenterWithX:(double)x
{
    return CGPointMake(x, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2);
}

@end
```

**Implementing Code**

```
#import "FlexibleScreen.h"
```

...

```
CGRect headerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [FlexibleScreen getScreenSize].width, HEADER_HEIGHT);
CGRect footerFrame = CGRectMake(0, [FlexibleScreen getScreenSize].height-FOOTER_HEIGHT, [FlexibleScreen getScreenSize].width, FOOTER_HEIGHT);
```

...

```
[label setCenter:[FlexibleScreen getCenterWithY:0]];
```

**UPDATE:**
As I used this more I realized I wanted it to be a lot simpler. Here is my latest version [GitHub: UIScreen+Flexible](https://github.com/koreyhinton/UIScreenFlexible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts on it:

1. **Code:** I'd suggest to create a [Category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) on `UIScreen`. This is even more elegant than creating a separate class.
2. **Naming:** In Objective-C getter usually do not have the prefix *"get"*.
3. **General approach:** Without knowing the background of your app and any detailed implementation, it's not common to layout UIViews relatively to the screen. As you're using `UIViewControllers`, any additional view should be added as a subview to the `UIViewController's view`. This ensures that layout and orientation changes are handled for you and are automatically being applied to all subviews by the `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using more of what Core Graphics gives you. There are methods along the lines of `CGRectGetMaxX(rect)`, `CGRectGetMidY(rect)` and `CGRectGetWidth(rect)` that does that kind of basic math for you. It reads cleaner and other coders who are used to Objective-C will immediately recognize them and understand the code.

Also, there is some code duplication where you calculate the center x twice and the center y twice. You can introduce two private methods to get rid of that duplication (I've also removed the "get" prefix as it is not commonly used in Objective-C and switched to `CGFloat` instead of `double`).

(If you really want to get rid of code duplication then you can create a method to get the bounds of the main screen. I did so in the code below)

```
+(CGRect)screenBounds
{
    return [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
}

+(CGFloat)centerX 
{
    return CGRectGetMidX([self screenBounds]);
}

+(CGFloat)centerY 
{
    return CGRectGetMidY([self screenBounds]);
}

+(CGPoint)center
{
    return CGPointMake([self centerX], [self centerY]);
}

+(CGPoint)centerWithY:(CGFloat)y
{
    return CGPointMake([self centerX], y);
}

+(CGPoint)centerWithX:(CGFloat)x
{
    return CGPointMake(x, [self centerY]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some changes I've made so far to [FlexibleScreen (GitHub)](https://github.com/koreyhinton/FlexibleScreen):

### 1. Status Bar Height

I also found that the status bar height plays a role into how much height is left on-screen if the status bar is present so I added this method which will be used by +getScreenSize to report an accurate screen size:

```
+(double)statusBarHeight
{
    double statusBarHeight = 0;
    if (![UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden){
        statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
    }
    return statusBarHeight;
}
```

### 2. Global Import FlexibleScreen

I also imported FlexibleScreen.h in *-Prefix.ch so that it was globally accessible without having to import in each file. I will eventually change FlexibleScreen to be a category like Florain Mielke suggested and that way I won't have to import it at all.